# Bash sort by file name like GNOME does

Tags: file, bash, sorting, gnome, ls

Bash is really annoying me with the way that it sorts it's files with the `sort` command and can't seem to find a way around this. When I sort the files with GNOME though by name, it shows it exactly how I want. I'm trying to sort by real order but the 10's and 1's mess everything up when sorting in bash. Here's how bash sorts a sample of my files:

```
HeadsetBatteryBG_10@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_11@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_12@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_1@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_13@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_14@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_15@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_16@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_17@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_2@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_3@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_4@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_5@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_6@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_7@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_8@2x.png
HeadsetBatteryBG_9@2x.png
```

I see what it's doing here, but is there anywhere to sort a list like this in bash how it SHOULD be sorted? With the numbers in real numerical order instead of this strange thing that it's doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sort -k2 -t_ -n [file]
```

That will sort numerically (-n) on the 2nd field (-k2) using _ as the field separator (-t_).

(Shamelessly stolen from [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/79338/in-bash-how-to-sort-strings-with-numbers-in-them))

Answer (score 2):

even simpler, assuming GNU sort: `sort -V`

```
   -V, --version-sort
          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the list this generates ignore case? adding the -f option seems to do literally nothing with the -V there